# Bind an array of arbitrary length to SQLite query

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I need to run a SQLite query using an array of parameters that has unknown length at compile time (I'm using FMDB, but can work with native SQLite if necessary).  So far, I've been manually inserting the correct number of bindings into the string based on the array length:

```
func getBindString (_ arrayCount: Int) -> String {
    return [String](repeating: "?", count: arrayCount).joined(separator: ",")
}

let someArray = ["foo","bar"]
let sqlString = "delete from someTable where someColumn in (\(getBindString(someArray.count)))"
db.executeUpdate(sqlString, withArgumentsIn: someArray)
/* delete from someTable where someColumn in ('foo','bar') */
```

which just feels really inelegant.  Is there any "proper" way of handling this?  Everything I could find online was several years out of date and all recommended interpolating the values directly, which is even worse.

Comment: @matt - Interpolating the values, themselves, rather than `?` placeholders, is worse, IMHO, because you're then manually inserting quotation marks into the SQL and can have problems is the values, themselves have any quotation marks or anything subject to SQL string escaping. By building the SQL with the appropriate number of `?` placeholders, you avoid a whole series of possible problems.

Comment: @Rob Nice point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what's "inelegant" about this. You are working in a string-based language (SQL), and you are very neatly forming the string in real time.

Your code isn't identically what I'd write, personally; I don't like string interpolation where it isn't needed, and it isn't needed here, so I would propose something more like this (I also think it's nice to use `map` rather than `Array(repeating:)`):

```
let someArray = ["foo","bar"]
let bindString = someArray.map{_ in "?"}.joined(separator: ",")
let sqlString = "delete from someTable where someColumn in (" + bindString + ")"
```

If you have to form a string like `bindString` many times, then by all means turn it into a utility function. But then I would write it as an extension on Array:

```
extension Array {
    var bindString : String {
        return "(" + self.map{_ in "?"}.joined(separator: ",") + ")"
    }
}
```

That way, your string construction would look like this:

```
let someArray = ["foo","bar"]
let sqlString = "delete from someTable where someColumn in " + someArray.bindString
```

But all of that is purely stylistic tweaking; there was *nothing* wrong with what you were doing.

Comment: There is not much natural collection for this extension: for the purpose of feeding `value IN (?,...)`, a Set does as well as an Array. GRDB defines a global function: [`databaseQuestionMarks(count:)`](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/v0.106.1/GRDB/Core/Utils.swift#L23-L25)